# how to find the ppa of a package found in launchpad?

Tags: 10.04, apt, package-management, ppa

I am trying to install a program (valgrind) which needs libc6-dbg. On the other hand, I cannot install libc6-dbg because:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   libc6-dbg: Depends: libc6 (= 2.11.1-0ubuntu7) but 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.2 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

which means I have a newer version of libc6 installed. However:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg=2.11.1-0ubuntu7.2
```

doesn't find anything. I am guessing I need to add the PPA containing that package, which is where I ran out of luck.

I found the package I need here (my ubuntu is Lucid): https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/i386/libc6-dbg/2.11.1-0ubuntu7.2, however, I can't seem to figure out what I should do to get `apt-get` to see and install this package.

Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-dbg` packages provide debug symbols for programs and libraries provided by the packages that are named like them but without `-dbg`. (Sometimes they provide debug symbols for a whole group packages, typically whose names start like them without `-dbg` and then contain more text.)

In this case, you have `libc6` installed (that's a core package without which no Ubuntu system can run), and you want to install `libc6-dbg`. This must correspond exactly to the *installed* version of `libc6`. Getting a separate version of `libc6-dbg` from a PPA that didn't correspond to the installed version of `libc6` would be very bad--it would not be usable.

As [this page indicates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc6&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), on a Lucid system both `libc6` and (if it is installed) `libc6-dbg` should be at version `2.11.1-0ubuntu7.10`. So it looks like you have an old version of `libc6` installed (which is possibly vulnerable to well-known security bugs!), for which `libc6-dbg` may no longer be available.

Not only do you have an old version of `libc6`, but your information about what the latest versions of `libc6` and `libc6-dbg` is out of date. Try this to correct it:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If you're installing packages on the command-line, you should always run that first (unless you've run it just recently).

Then run this to upgrade your system's packages (including `libc6`):

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then try again:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg
```

If that still doesn't work, check your Software Sources (by going to the Update Manager and clicking the Settings... button at the lower-left corner). Click on the Updates Tab. Make sure that `Important security updates (lucid-security)` and `Recommended updates (lucid-updates)` are enabled (checked).

[image: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, Software Sources window, Updates tab]

<sub>That image is taken from [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Updates_Tab), written by `Contributors to the Ubuntu documentation wiki` and [licensed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/License) under [CC-BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). Content on Ask Ubuntu including this post is also [licensed](https://askubuntu.com/faq#editing) that way. Thus my incorporation of that image is permitted here.</sub>

Then after enabling those software sources, run these commands again:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And then try again:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg
```

Comment: That was it. The guy who had installed this ubuntu had somehow disabled `lucid-security` and `lucid-updates`

Answer (score 2):

In general (answering your title question): for searching/adding ppa's you could use [Y PPA Manager](https://launchpad.net/y-ppa-manager).

After adding you update your sources and install the package from source you want...

Comment: That's quite nice! I hope others who came for the real question in the title wouldn't miss your post

Answer (score 1):

You should update your system, for example with

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If that doesn't help make sure you have the security updates enabled.

The current version of `libc6` in Lucid is *2.11.1-0ubuntu7.10*, the corresponding `libc6-dbg` is available from the official software sources.

Comment: My synaptic says the latest version of `libc6` is `2.11.1-0ubuntu7.2` and `libc6-dbg` is `2.11.1-0ubuntu7`! I have already tried with `apt-get update` and `upgrade` on `libc6` and `libc6-dev` (a total upgrade also says there are no packages for upgrade (my system is up-to-date))

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'libc6-dbg' is the package name, and '=2.11.1-0ubuntu7.2' is the version. Try using

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg
```

Or use the synaptic package manager.

These two methods will install a newer version of libc6-dbg. If you have to have the older one, you can download the .deb file for it on the right side of the launchpad page you linked.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. Since it didn't work, I tried with the specific version. Also, synaptic shows `=2.11.1-0ubuntu7` as the latest version. That is why I am looking for a way (possibly by adding the right PPA) to let it get the newer version from a different repository.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an update of libc6 and libc6-dbg would help?
There are newer versions (with security updates) of both packages available:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/i386/libc6/2.11.1-0ubuntu7.10

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/i386/libc6-dbg/2.11.1-0ubuntu7.10

I think 2.11.1-0ubuntu7 is not in the repositories anymore.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: I have tried `update` followed by `upgrade libc6`, and `upgrade libc6-dev`, but it didn't upgrade anything. The problem persists