# How can I know the source ppa of an installed package?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

I have a package (xserver-xorg-video-intel) from ppa sources. Since I have more than one ppa sources for this package in my package management I am not sure which one is the source. So I wonder if I can learn this using apt-get or dbpkg etc. Related question: If I have various ppa's for a given package, will apt-get change the ppa if it finds a new version of the package in any ppa? I am asking since I use an alternative ppa for xserver-xorg-video-intel as the driver in the official one leads to errors in hibernate/sleep.

Comment: See if this helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/150884/how-to-find-the-ppa-of-a-package-found-in-launchpad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to those answers running `apt-cache madison <package-name>` from a terminal may shed more light

```
hob@hobgoblin:~$ apt-cache madison clementine
clementine | 1.0.1-554-geded1da~precise | http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine-dev/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
clementine | 1.0.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1 | http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/universe amd64 Packages
clementine | 1.0.1+dfsg-2ubuntu1 | http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/universe Sources
clementine | 1.0.1-554-geded1da~precise | http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine-dev/ubuntu/ precise/main Sources
```

Answer (score 3):

`apt-cache policy <package-name>` gives similar information to `apt-cache madison <package-name>`, but in a different format:

```
$ apt-cache policy disper
disper:
  Installed: 0.3.0-1
  Candidate: 0.3.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.3.0-1 0
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.3.0 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/disper-dev/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```